Understanding Pointers to Arrays in C++
In C++, there is a concept of a pointer to an array, where it is said to point to the "whole array" rather than just the first element. This idea confuses me. How can a pointer point to an entire array? Shouldn't it only point to the first element?

&arr will have the type int (*)[10]. That is, it's a pointer to an array of ten int elements. If you want to visualize it, then use pen and paper to draw the array as a long rectangular box. Then draw a separate box, label it &arr, and draw an arrow from &arr to the beginning of the array box. That's how pointers work.

Also be careful, if you print the pointers &arr and &arr[0] as suggested by @3CxEZiVlQ, then that will print the same address. The problem with this is that &arr and &arr[0] have different types: &arr have the type int (*)[10] (as I mentioned above), but &arr[0] have the type int *, because it's a pointer to a single int element.

The problem is that I am being told that int()[10] points to the entire array of 10 elements whereas a normal integer pointer only points to the first element. I don't quite get how int()[10] points to the entire array of 10 integers.

Arrays do not always decay to pointers. See Array-to-pointer decay.

If you intend to build solid understanding of C++, don't rush into pointers and raw arrays. Start with references, values std::array and std::string. keep pointers waiting for a later time.

It was mostly a thing in "C" in C++ avoid "pointer arithmetic" whenever you can. C++ as std::vector + std::array which help you manage arrays as objects (even return them from functinos). For passing (parts of) arrays use std::span. And forget things like pointer decay ever existed.

Read C++ core guidelines ES.42, keep use of pointers simple and straightforward. Pointers should only refer to single objects. Pointer arithmetic is fragile and easy to get wrong, the source of many, many bad bugs and security violations. span is a bounds-checked, safe type for accessing arrays of data. And arrays are not single objects (note : C++ calls integers/doubles objects too)

So TLDR, you can represent the start of an array by a pointer, but it is NOT an array

How can a pointer point to an entire array?  How can a pointer point to the first element?

You are confusing the value of the pointer (i.e. the address that it holds) with what it is pointing to. If you dereference a pointer you get the value that it points to. So if you dereference a pointer to the first element of an array, you get the first element of the array, and if you dereference a pointer to the whole array, you get the whole array. These are not the same thing, syntactically or semantically.

Lets draw it out for you...
First we have out array:

+--------+--------+-----+--------+
| arr[0] | arr[1] | ... | arr[9] |
+--------+--------+-----+--------+

Now lets add some pointers:

         +--------+--------+-----+--------+
&arr --> | arr[0] | arr[1] | ... | arr[9] |
         +--------+--------+-----+--------+
         ^        ^              ^
         |        |              |
         &arr[0]  &arr[1]        &arr[9]

Here we can see that &arr will point to the array, but it's a pointer to the whole array, not a pointer to a single element like &arr[0].

To perhaps show it in another way: If you don't know, then arr[i] is exactly the same as *(arr + i). That is, you take a pointer to the first element and add the index to get a pointer to that element, then dereference it.
The important part here is that arr + 1 is a pointer to an element.
Now lets say we store the pointer to the array in a variable:
int (*arr_ptr)[10] = &arr;

With this we know that arr_ptr[0] is the same as *(arr_ptr + 0) which is the same as *arr_ptr.
What we also know that arr_ptr[1] will be the same as *(arr_ptr + 1).
Lets take the drawing above, and add the pointers arr_ptr and arr_ptr + 1:

            +--------+--------+-----+--------+
arr_ptr --> | arr[0] | arr[1] | ... | arr[9] | ... unknown memory
            +--------+--------+-----+--------+
            ^        ^              ^        ^
            |        |              |        |
            &arr[0]  &arr[1]        &arr[9]  arr_ptr + 1

This drawing shows that arr_ptr (and thus &arr) is a pointer to the whole array.

so &arr and &arr[0] point to the first element?

@HumblePenguin No, they have the same value, i.e. point to the same location in memory. But only &arr[0] points to the first element of the array.

I apologize but I still don't get this. Isn't arr_ptr and &arr still just a pointer to the first element? How is it pointing to the entire array?

@HumblePenguin You could have two pointers to the same location, but they can still have different semantics and types (pointer to an array, pointer to a single element in the array).

It's fine hair to be splitting (in my experience of actual use), but nonetheless the distinction is still there.

struct Foo { int a; int b; }; Foo foo;  Foo* pfoo = &foo; int* pint = &foo.a; Both pfoo and pint will have the same value, but point to different things, and those pointers have different types.

What really changes is the behavior of pointer arithmetic, incrementing/decrementing or adding/subtracting an offset to the pointer, because they are two different types of pointers.
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    void *arrPlusOne = (void *)(&arr+1);
    void *arrItemPlusOne = (void *)(&arr[0]+1);
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", (void *)&arr, (void *)&(arr[0]), arrPlusOne, arrItemPlusOne);
    
    printf("array pointer step: %ld\n", ((char *)arrPlusOne - (char *)&arr));
    printf("array item pointer step: %ld\n", ((char *)arrItemPlusOne - (char *)&arr));
    
    return 0;
}

The output might be something like this:
0x7fff4b58ce80 0x7fff4b58ce80 0x7fff4b58cea8 0x7fff4b58ce84
array pointer step: 40
array item pointer step: 4

The cast to char pointer is to allow arithmetic subtraction which is not allowed on void pointers.
Cast to void pointers in printf() is required because is a variadic function.
If you run this code you will see that the third and fourth pointers point to different memory locations even though the code always adds 1, depending on the processor architecture and type sizes.

Much like a class/struct can be thought of as a container of data members, an array can be thought of as a container of elements (and in fact, std::array is part of the standard Containers library).
You can have a pointer to a single member/element, and you can have a pointer to the entire container as a whole. Both pointers may point at the same address in memory, but the things they are pointing at are logically and semantically different things.
A pointer tells you not only WHERE it is pointing at, but WHAT it is pointing at.

It will become evident from the following test:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10];
    printf("%lu, %lu", sizeof(a), sizeof(a[0]));
    return 0;
}

Output is:

40, 4

Therefore, an int array of 10 elements have a size of 40, whereas a single int has a size of 4. Therefore the size of your array is:
size_of_unit * number_of_units
